# Scraping information in a span located under nested span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get live weather data with web scraping. I was thinking about using BeautifulSoup for this.

```html
<span class="Column--precip--3JCDO">
  <span class="Accessibility--visuallyHidden--H7O4p">Chance of Rain</span>
  3%
</span>
```

I want to get the 3% out of this container. I already managed to get data from the website using this code snippet for another section.

```
temp_value = soup.find("span", {"class":"CurrentConditions--tempValue--MHmYY"}).get_text(strip=True)
```

I tried the same for the rain_forecast

```
rain_forecast = soup.find("span", {"class": "Column--precip--3JCDO"}).get_text(strip=True)
```

But the output my console is delivering is `--` for `print(rain_forecast)`.
The only difference I can see is that between the "text" that should be gotten from the span there is another span.

Another way I came across on Stack Overflow is to use Selenium, because the data has not yet been loaded into the variable and therefore the output is `--`.

But I don't know if this is overkill for my application, or if there is an simpler solution for this problem.

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: `class="Column--precip--3JCDO"` I'm just guessing, but it seems like this might be a dynamically generated class name that would be different each time the page is loaded (particularly the `3JCDO` part -- that smells a lot like a random string).  Are you sure this exact class name is always used?

Comment: This is the URL:

https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/a0e0a5a98f7825e44d5b44b26d6f3c2e76a8d70e0426d099bff73e764af3087a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get table of today forecast you can use this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

url = "https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/a0e0a5a98f7825e44d5b44b26d6f3c2e76a8d70e0426d099bff73e764af3087a"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

today_forecast = []
for a in soup.select(".TodayWeatherCard--TableWrapper--globn a"):
    today_forecast.append(
        t.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for t in a.find_all(recursive=False)
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    today_forecast, columns=["Time of day", "Degrees", "Text", "Chance of rain"]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Time of day Degrees                 Text          Chance of rain
0     Morning    11 °        Partly Cloudy                      --
1   Afternoon    20 °        Partly Cloudy                      --
2     Evening    14 °  Partly Cloudy Night  Rain Chance of Rain 3%
3   Overnight    10 °               Cloudy  Rain Chance of Rain 5%
```

Comment: This was working pretty good for me! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Assuming you have your HTML content in 'html_content'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the parent span and extract the text, excluding the nested span's text
rain_forecast = soup.find("span", {"class": "Column--precip--3JCDO"}).contents[-1].strip()

print(rain_forecast)
```